# XAMLParseException when loading loose style XAML in same assembly: creating type failed

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-namespaces, resourcedictionary, xamlparseexception

I would like for the user of my WPF application to be able to choose between two styles: the default WPF style and my own custom style. I've made a Resource Dictionary which includes all the style elements of the custom style. The resource dictionary is located in the same project.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Practicum21_Ben_Vandenberk">
```

...

```
    <Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BestellingDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CategorieDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:KlantDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LeverancierDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ProduktDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WerknemerDetail}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
```

When I try to load this dictionary to App.Current.Resources using the following code, I get an XAMLParseException: "creating a Type from the text local:MainWindow failed".

```
ResourceDictionary dic = new ResourceDictionary();
dic.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
```

I've been searching for over two hours now.

[WPF Loose XAML ResourceDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465443/wpf-loose-xaml-resourcedictionary)

On several threads people suggest to add "assembly=" to the xmlns at the top of the loose XAML. If I do this though, the XAML file itself won't build anymore.

[Error: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:NameSpace.Properties}Settings'.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156723/error-cannot-create-unknown-type-clr-namespacenamespace-propertiessettings/16280555#16280555)

Here people suggested to set the build action of the XAML to 'page' but this was already the case for my XAML file...

I'm pretty new to programming and my understanding is pretty limited, but I'm usually able to solve problems by browsing the web. Not this time though.

I figure it has to be something trivial which I can't find due to my lack of understanding. Or am I tackling my original problem (letting the user choose between 2 styles) in an altogether wrong fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be loading the Xaml file at runtime, you shouldn't need to compile it.  Try changing the build action to 'Resource', then add the `assembly=` qualifiers to your namespace imports like the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465443/wpf-loose-xaml-resourcedictionary) suggests.

Alternatively, build the Xaml file as 'Page', but give it a class name so you can instantiate it with a constructor:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Practicum21_Ben_Vandenberk.AlternateResources"
  ...>

App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new AlternateResources());
```

If you go that route, you shouldn't need to add `assembly=` qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! 

When I try your first suggestion, with the assembly information, it won't build as before:
Error 2 The type reference cannot find a public type named 'MainWindow'. 

The second suggestion lets me add the AlternateResources() to the MergedDictionaries at runtime, but the styles won't get applied. While previously, if I commented out all the window styles (above), all the other styles did get applied. It's getting late though, maybe I'll see things clearer tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Odd.  If you change the build action to `Resource` then there shouldn't be anything **to** build.  In the second case, are you continuing to `Clear()` the resources before adding the `AlternateResources` dictionary?  I left that line out of my answer, but I didn't mean to imply that you should remove it.  I don't know whether you need it or not.  Also, can you check to see that a constructor is getting generated for `AlternateResources` that calls `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: Hey, when I tried again this morning, setting the build action to resource and adding the assembly= qualifier, it worked like a charm! Thanks for the quick and accurate reply!